# RESTFUL web service response parsing issue

Tags: php, xml, rest

I am getting the restful web service response as well. But I am not able to parse it properly

my code looks like this

```
include 'RestClient.class.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Client Profile



$url = "http://localhost/lgen/index.php/api/client";

$ex = RestClient::get($url,array('requestType' =>'viewClientProfile', 
                                                        'username' => 'uname', 
                                                                 'pass' =>'pass'));

echo $response = $ex->getResponse();

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

when print $response I am getting data on browser but while trying to parse it am not getting any kind of data

Comment: so what's the question? Did you get any errors?

Comment: when print $response I am getting data on browser but while trying to parse it am not getting any kind of data

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $response = $ex->getResponse();
```

You are creating and echoing a variable at the same time.

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($ex->getResponse());
var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: I have a xml like


<xml><item><user_client_id>78</user_client_id><company_name>cytech</company_name><company_vat>qwe</company_vat><company_coc>asd</company_coc><company_house_number>123</company_house_number><company_house_number_addition>345</company_house_number_addition><company_zipcode>456</company_zipcode><company_city>mnb</company_city><company_street>zxc</company_street><state_state_name>contry2state2</state_state_name><countryName>country2</countryName></item></xml>

how do I parse it using simple xml?

Comment: Read the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and have a look at the [Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: Hi Simone I can print the response but not able to parse it